# Raspberry Pi fails to boot from USB HDD

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch

I wrote the [Raspbian Stretch image with Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) to my USB HDD using Win32 Disk Imager. I resized partition 2 using `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` (my usb drive) by deleting the partition and recreating it with the same start and a new end (the default one of fdisk) on my Pi 3 that has Jessie installed.

After rebooting I expanded the filesystem of partition 2 by executing `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2`. `df -h` showed that everything went right. I deleted all partitions on a 4GB SD card, created a new "W95 FAT32 (LBA)" partition (both steps using fdisk), created a new vfat filesystem (`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sda1`, my HDD wasn't attached) and copied the files from the HDD's boot partition to my SD card.

I changed the cmdline.txt's `root` option on my SD card to `root=/dev/sda2`. So my cmdline.txt now looks like that:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

After trying to boot from the SD card with the HDD attached the Raspberry Pi logos at the top of the screen appear and after about 14 seconds when the HDD is ready those messages are printed:

```
[     xxx.xxx] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[     xxx.xxx] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

They are also printed when executing `dmesg` on Jessie.
After these messages the Pi reboots, again showing the rainbow screen, and everything starts again.

I don't want to boot from USB by setting an OTP-bit because I still want to be able to boot from SD card.

Is it possible that my HDD spins up to slow (14 seconds are quite a bit)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the bit in OTP you can't boot from an external drive. The Raspberry is simply hardwired to search for the boot partition on the SD card. You can move the root partition to the external drive as you've already found out. I believe the reboot loop is a different problem. Did you connect the external drive directly to the Raspberry? If yes then you need to connect it through a powered USB hub. The external drive probably draws too much power during powering up thereby depriving the Raspberry itself of power causing it to reboot.

Comment: Yes, I connected my drive directly which always works well when I use my Pi with Raspbian Jessie only on an SD card. It didn't work with  my Pi 2 but since the Pi 3 everything is alright.

Comment: The Pi 3 has a better powersupply than the Pi 2 that's why it works with the Pi 3.

Comment: Do you know what else could cause the reboot?

Comment: Power problems are the main cause of reboots. Since it works with the new Pi you can rule out any other cause.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was unclear. When I insert an SD card having Raspbian Jessie installed into my Pi 3 I can connect my HDD and use it normally. But when I want to boot it using an SD card with the Stretch boot partition my Pi keeps rebooting.

Comment: You're changing the question now. The original question as reflected by the title was "Raspberry Pi fails to boot from USB HDD". I gave you an answer to that one. If you have a new question then please ask a new question. Besides that the comments are not suitable for extended discussion as the moderators probably will tell us if we go on with this.

Comment: Did you flip the USB boot bit using the config.txt hack so the Pi 3 knows to move on from SD to USB after 10 seconds?

Comment: OTP switching will still prioritise SD over USB, if an SD is present. It doesn't only bit from USB after the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Can your raspberry Pi support the Hard drive (powering it)?
Try booting the Pi without changing any partitions after burning the raspbian image to the HDD.

BTW the OTP bit does not mean you can't boot from an SD card again.

Anyways why do you need the 4 GB SD card? Why not boot everything from the HDD? Make sure you have an adequate power supply and cables, thin cables might create problems.

Comment: Whoops... Did not see that this post was this old. Sorry if i bumped it!